# c++/cli Multithreading Socket and form

Tags: c++-cli

Could anyone point me in the right direction with this, I seem to loop around the web in vain...

```
private: System::Void loginButton_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
             mLogin* lgn;
             string text = marshal_as<string>(subjectName->Text);

             if (lgn->login(&text) == "Master")
             {
                 delete this;
                 mSockServ server;
                 vMaster master;
                 Thread^ newThread = gcnew Thread(gcnew ThreadStart(master, &vMaster::ShowDialog));
                 newThread->Start();

                 //master.ShowDialog();
                 server.sockInit();
             }
             else if (lgn->login(&text) == "Slave")
             {
                 delete this;
                 vSlave slave;
                 mSockClnt client;
                 Thread^ newThread = gcnew Thread(gcnew ThreadStart(client, &mSockClnt::sockInit));
                 newThread->Start();
                 //client.sockInit(text);
                 slave.ShowDialog();
             }
             else if (lgn->login(&text) == "No")
             {
                MessageBox::Show("Not a valid username or password");
             }
         }
```

I just want to start a new form in a new thread so it would run concurrently with a socket server or client which I would also like to start in a new thread. I can't seem to start neither the socket nor the form, this are my errors:

Error   1   error C3352: 'ShowDialog' : the specified function does not match the delegate type 'void (void)'

Error   2   error C3352: 'void mSockClnt::sockInit(std::string)' : the specified function does not match the delegate type 'void (void)'

although I made sure that sockInit is of type void...

Thank you.

Comment: Just add two methods.

Comment: If I don't separate the socket from the form by thread or something, one just waits' for the other.